Chrome extension – Navigator.writeText() returning Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeText')
Goal
Copy selected text to the clipboard
Environment – Locally testing extension via chrome://extensions
Expected behaviour
To select some text and succesfully copy it to the clipboard when select copyLink from context menu
Current behaviour
My extension errors out and shows the below error:
Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeText') at 

Context menu
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    parentId: 'Main',
    title: 'Copy Link',
    id: 'copyLink',
    contexts: ['selection']
});

Checking for clicks on contextMenu
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((e) => {
    if (e.menuItemId == 'copyLink') {
        // this successfully logs the text in background.js
        console.log(e.selectionText);
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.selectionText).then(
            () => {
                console.log('Aync: Copying to clipboard was successful');
            },
            (err) => {
                console.error('Async: Could not copy text: ', err);
            }
        );
    }
});

Why is this occuring? My browser supports Navigator.clipboard.writeText. I do not want to use     document.execCommand('copy') as it is deprecated

It is not a duplicate! What was suggested is using     document.execCommand('copy');. I do not want to use this as it is deprecated.

That doesn't make this question non-duplicate, it means the other question needs a new or better answer. You can put a bounty on it if you want.

Please take a look at this: chrome-extensions-samples/functional-samples/cookbook.offscreen-clipboard-write at main · GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples · GitHub

Thanks @nkalvi that resolved myissue!

Happy to hear it - good luck with your extension!
